Azure Virtual Desktop - the VM unable to be added in the host pool
Since 4 days, I'm trying to deploy Azure Virtual Desktop in my subscription by it always fails giving this error: "The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. (code : ResourceDeploymentFailure". Before I was able to deploy it successfully. But now, after around 17 min, it fails with the above error. I tried it in multiple Azure subscriptions but I got the same error. IT is there a problem with this feature currently? How can I fix it?
Thanks.
